# How to set spinner text in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

I have 2 `spinners` populated with the `same array`. I want to display the first item of array in first `spinner` (and here no problems) and to display the second item in second `spinner` (I am not having any idea . How I can do this).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried  spin.setSelection(1);

Comment: you can also create two array adapters , first having first elements , and second having second elements , and then pass those adapters to the spinner

Comment: @A.S. : post it as answer for your +1 man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On spinner it is simple to set deafult selection with `spin.setSelection(YOUR_NUMBER);`